# How can I remove mold from the underside of garage roof sheathing?

Tags: mold

Home inspector found mold in roof under sheathing in my garage.  Mold professional says they spray a fungicide to kill it and then spray with a tinted paint.  Extremely pricey!  You cant clean it off because of the roof nails everywhere.  Is this the only way?

Comment: Surely you can spray the fungicide and paint yourself. Do you need a mold abatement certificate for any reason?

Comment: The buyer has not asked for a certificate.  In my state, mold remediation does not require special licensing.  My contractor tells me he can do it for much less.  He is at least a licensed contractor. It is a fairly large area.

Comment: Dry ice blasting will also remove it, but that would likely also require hiring a professional.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you’re the “seller” and the “buyer’s” inspector found the problem.

In real estate sales, I think it is better for the seller to reduce the asking price and let the buyer “fix” the problem. If you try to fix the problem, I can guarantee you that it won’t be good enough and you’ll be re-negotiating the cost and repair later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they will let you do it since it was found on an inspection but I would spray the area with 3% hydrogen peroxide and water mixture this will kill the mold if you want to seal it after dry regular paint should encapsulate the wood but if you use a marine grade anti fouling paint or a paint where you can add the fungicide that would do the trick. My concern would be why was the wood wet painting may trap moisture from a leak in the wood making the problem bigger later on.

Comment: The inspector said it was because the dryer vented into the garage.  It actually just looks like dust.    The vent is being rerouted.

Comment: A dryer could do it.